# Galaxy Note caught in Cyanogenmod initialization loop

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-note

My original Galaxy Note has been replaced with a Note 3. Hence, I was curious about installing Cyanogenmod on it. I did and it worked fine, a little while ago I wante to update to a newer version, that also had a different desktop UI than the previous install.
This time something went wrong. I'm now caught in a boot lopp with the greeting Cyanogenmod "cat" on the screen. I can also do the vol down+Power reboot and is then presented with the recovery screen. However, Odin doesn't seem to get any contact with the Note.

Do I have any options? Id so, what are they?

Comment: I've just added the `boot-loop` tag to your question. Please take a look into [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) for the "first-aid" offered there – so we don't need to repeat that again :) Then let us know what you tried, whether you succeeded, and if not where you're stuck. Good luck!

Comment: To use Odin you need to be in Download mode, not recovery. Download is Volume Down + Home + Power button.

Comment: @Izzy Sorry about the tags, first posting here, takes some time to get used to. Ryan Conrad  Nice tip, didn't know about that difference. Will check it out and get back here.

Comment: Was not to critisize – information only :) We are fully aware that the site has is complexities, especially to new users. We're just trying to be helpful. :)